# "it" for a transitive verb, like a dummy pronoun?

Tags: verbs, transitive-verbs

Is the following sentence correct?

> We refine it when we can revisit a vertex.

The "it" refers to nothing (it seems to be the dummy pronoun), but the sentence seems correct to me.  I think "it" is needed, because "refine" is a transitive verb.  What I want to say in this sentence is that we refine the circumstances when we can revisit a vertex.

Is there some grammar rule that would back my claim that the sentence is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're sure ***it*** doesn't refer to anything (i.e. - something which you refine in the specified circumstances), just don't include it. The text is at the very least "unusual" (I have absolutely no idea what it might mean, in *any* real-world context), but syntactically it's perfectly valid with ***it*** (something gets refined in that situation), or without ***it*** (we refine / specify more precisely *the time at which we can or will be able to revisit a vertex*).

Comment: Thanks, FumbleFingers, for your comment. The Oxford dictionary says that that "refine" is only transitive, so I thought that "it" is required, even though it is kind of dummy.  But then I checked the Merriam-Webster dictionary, and indeed "refine" can be intransitive too, and has the meaning you described and that I need.  That solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Much depends on your *exact* definition of a "transitive verb". *Q. What does an oil refinery do? A. It **refines**!* Strictly speaking we should say that's an intransitive usage, but in practice A's response would be nonsense if it weren't for the contextually implied direct object *(It refines **oil**)*.  And consider the full OED's most recent citation for the "intransitive" form: *As their taste **refines,** jewellery buyers usually turn their attention towards small, delicate things*. Same thing there - contextually implied *the jewellery buyers refined **their tastes**.*

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers, again for your insight! I wish I could mark your comments as the answer to my question.

Comment: I didn't post an "Answer" because I had already voted to close the question as "Unclear" (precisely *because* you haven't edited the question to clarify exactly what meaning you intend the example sentence to convey). Note that if I cast a closevote like that, I *hope* (but don't necessarily *expect*) that the question will be amended to give more details - in which case I will happily reconsider my vote, and cancel it if appropriate.

Comment: FumbleFingers, I didn't realize there was a vote, and that perhaps I should add some more details - I've got no notification.  I edited the question, and added some more details.

Comment: Haha - your added "clarification" *We refine the circumstances when we can revisit a vertex* still contains exactly the same ambiguity! It could either mean we refine [something else] ***during** the visits*, or  that we refine the ***timing** of the visits*. If there ***is*** a "something else", you need the word ***it*** to reference it. If not, the word ***it*** should not be present.

Comment: Anyway, I've retracted my closevote and *tried* to provide a more generally applicable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "it" refers to nothing

No!  This is not true.  The "it" probably refers to a term mentioned in the previous sentence.  If this was indeed a standalone sentence, then "it" shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thank you, QuIcKmAtHs, for your answer.  After your answer, and FumbleFingers comments, I decided just to remove "it" from the sentence.  Initially I thought that "it" served as a dummy pronoun, but it's better just to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The verb ***refine*** is "awkward" here. It could mean 1) ***purify, distil, make more concentrated*** (referring to something mentioned earlier) or 2) ***fine-tune, revise, make more precise*** (referring to the timing of the visits).

There's also ambiguity as to whether we're talking about times when it would be *possible* to visit (regardless of whether we do or not) or times when we *actually manage* to visit (by implication, with some difficulty). But I'll ignore that aspect.

The short answer to OP's question is that if there ***is*** a "something mentioned earlier" (sense #1 above), the word ***it*** is required, to refer back to whatever that "something" is. If not (sense #2), ***it*** should not be present.

---

But I think perhaps what's *really* confusing OP is better illustrated by looking at a similar construction involving ***when*** and an ambiguous / dummy ***it***...

> *I like [it] when you (infinitive verb phrase)*
>    e.g.
>    [*I like **it** when you smile*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20like%20it%20when%20you%20smile%22) (10 hits in Google Books)
>    [*I like when you smile*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20like%20when%20you%20smile%22) (5 hits)

...where both forms do occur, but they mean exactly the same thing. As the figures suggest, we usually *do* include that "dummy pronoun", but I think it would be pointlessly pedantic to argue that either version is more "correct". Consider this more "generic" example...

> *I fall asleep as soon as I go to bed at 11 o'clock every night, but I always know [it] when you come home after midnight*

...where ***know*** could be replaced by various alternatives (***hear, resent, hate, like, record<sup>1</sup>,...***). And in all cases, the word ***it*** is optional - if present, it can be thought of as a "forward reference" to the activity specified later (***your smiling, your coming home late***), or simply a "dummy".

My feeling is this kind of *optional* "dummy ***it***" can only occur with *verbs of perception / reaction*. It certainly can't apply with OP's verb ***refine***, or with any "synonyms" for *either* of the two senses I defined in the first sentence of my answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> I thought it was worth including something like ***record*** here even though it requires a bit of "creative context" to make sense (perhaps an unhappy wife recording her drunken husband's behaviour, to support her pending divorce application). The point being that ***recording*** the time of coming home is effectively a "reaction" to that event.